# How to get ASCII of number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ascii

I am aware of `name.charCodeAt(0)`. I am having issued with the following code, so I want a solution for below.

```
var number= 2;
var t = number.charCodeAt(0);
console.log(t);
```

The answer needs to be in ASCII. I am getting the log as 2 and not as ASCII value 50. What can be the issue?

Comment: you might want to make number a String, then.

Comment: Are you asking how to cast a number to a string? `2 + ""` or `String(2)`

Answer (score 3):

*ASCII* is a way of representing *String data*. You need to first convert your *Number* to *String*;

Remember also that *String* can have arbitrary length so you'll need to iterate over every character.

```
var x = 2,
    str_x = '' + x,
    chrs = Array.prototype.map.call(str_x, function (e) {return e.charCodeAt(0);});
chrs; // [50]
```

Finally, *JavaScript* works with *UTF-16/UCS-2* and not plain *ASCII*. Luckily the values for digits are the same in both so you don't have to do any further transformation here.

Comment: Thank you. Why we you used this "str_x = '' + x" ?

Comment: Second thing, when we can use simple casting, why there is a need to use the above complex code?

Comment: `'' + x` is a short way to get a String from something. The complex bit? Consider, what should the result be for `42`?

Comment: "Luckily the values for digits are the same in both so you don't have to do any further transformation" When code depends on that kind of magic, I feel a comment is warranted.

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast a number to a string first to use `.charCodeAt` to get the numerical character code.

```
var number = 2;
var t = String( number ).charCodeAt( 0 );
console.log( t ); // 50
```

Comment: If any of these answers correctly answered your question, choose the one you feel answered it best and click on the checkmark next to the vote number.

Answer (score 1):

Just convert the number to String and call the method on it.

```
var number = 2;
var numberInString = number.toString();
var code = numberInString.charCodeAt(0);
console.log(code);
```

Comment: Kindly mark the helpful answers **useful** by using the arrows next to the question :)